# Reset color of Node in Cocos3d

Tags: ios, colors, textures, cocos3d

I'm using Cocos3d to show a 3D Model. When I click on a node, I change the color of it.

Now I want to reset the color at the second click to the original texture (not only simple color, but patterns etc.). How can I do this?
(My problem is resetting the color and not to detect the second click!)

I change the color in the first click:

```
ccColor3B ccDARKMAGENTA = {139,0,139};
[aNode setColor:ccColor3B.ccDARKMAGENTA];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White is the no-color color:

```
[aNode setColor:ccColor3B.ccWHITE];
```